# Audi A5 sat nav through SD card

Tags: audio, audi

I am looking into buying an Audi A5 and from what i read on the Audi website and online you can only have the built in sat nav or the sd card slot but you cannot have the built in sat nav and the sd card slot.

so my question is can you purchase an sd card with all the sat nav information so you can have a sat nav but then use another sd card for music or other uses if you wish?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It is not clear from this question what mechanical problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @BobCross, does this qualify as purchasing question?

Comment: @theUg, I'd rather let other members of the community make that assessment.  We have quite a few active users now: what do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some notes before we get started to help you see the differences in option packages.

### Audi A5

**The Base** does **not** come standard with iPod *or* Bluetooth connectivity, but those are easy enough to add as standalone options. The absence of a `USB port` is much more troubling (to me at least). Instead of spending more money on inter-grading a `USB port` into the system, you have the option of loading mp3s *(or other music files you use)* onto a flash drive and forget about the `USB port` that you didn't get. Once you have placed your music onto an `SD card` you could use the `A5's standard SD slot`. However, a `USB` port can provide superior connections for portable mp3 players; the standard auxiliary jack is pretty basic technology.

**The Premium** comes with 18-inch alloy wheels, foglamps, a panoramic sunroof (coupe only), a power-operated vinyl roof (Cabriolet only), leather upholstery, single-zone automatic climate control, power front seats with driver lumbar adjustment, a tilt-telescopic steering wheel, the Multi-Media Interface system with a dash-mounted control knob and a ten-speaker audio system with an auxiliary input, an `SD card reader and satellite radio`.

**The Prestige**, or, the icing on the cake, goes over-the-top **adding** adaptive xenon headlamps that include LED running lights, a blind-spot warning system, keyless entry with push-button ignition, MMI Plus with navigation and a console-mounted joystick knob and a 14-speaker, 505-watt Bang & Olufsen audio system.

---

According to the above you can see that the A5 *does* in fact ship with *both* options. The navigation is now held in a 10gb hard drive, no more `DVD-based` navigation units.

If you end up purchasing a slightly older model that comes with a `DVD-based` navigation. Then I would suggest copying the `CD` onto an `SD card` and using *one* of the *two* SD card slots provided. This will dramatically increase map load times.

**`Note:`** According to the vehicle's user-manual it will advise that you use *at least* an `8GB SD-card`, but `MY2011` vehicle maps will need one twice the size (16GB).

**`Note:`** Also, you cannot have your music and your maps on one `SD-card`, you will need two separate cards if you want to do both. But, that's why they provide two slots. Just make sure to label them so you don't end up overwriting your navigation maps with music. Also, don't get rid of the `DVD` just in case you run you accidentally format it to put music on it.